# WebGL build freezes in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-webgl

I cannot take WebGL build because it freezes while building . I have tried to change emscripten settings but could not save my changes . How can I build it?

Comment: Wait, it takes a long time, even with my workstation (16GB ram, 16 Threads and 8GB of GPU compute available) it can take 15+ minutes for a simple project and does hang during the build process.

Comment: yes I have realized , now everything is cool thanks for advising

Comment: unity builds are epically slow, especially the first time.

Comment: yes you are right I have gained this experience , others were not that slow